# Robot Framwork error: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process

Tags: robotframework

Getting this error when I try and run a test. I had to uninstall and reinstall chrome some time back and this then started happening. My chromedriver version is correct for my browser also

> [ ERROR ] Calling method 'end_suite' of listener
> 'C:\Users\JRyan64\Projects\esp-case-management\tests\robot\Execution\ResultsListener.py'
> failed: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in
> position 2640: character  maps to 
> Tests.Robot.Tests.Cumulus.ESP.GS Portal.ADUX-11813.Test :: As a Po...
> | FAIL | Parent suite setup failed: WebDriverException: Message:
> unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there might be multiple reasons why you are getting this error:

- running as root or administrator
- chromedriver is not accessible, check $Path variable in "Environment Variables" or simply run chromedriver from command line to check if it's accessible.